# How can I generate code coverage for Swift packages on Linux or OS X?

Tags: linux, swift, xcode, macos

I am looking for a way to generate code coverage for a Swift package created using Swift Package Manager. On OS X I can achieve this using Xcode after running `swift package generate-xcodeproj` and running the test suite under Xcode at which point I have the standard coverage tools available to me.

Are there any tools out in the wild for that allow this to happen on OS X and Linux?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is actually possible by passing `--enable-code-coverage` to `swift test`

```
$ swift test --enable-code-coverage
```

That will generate an `.xctest` bundle in `.build/x86_64-unknown-linux/debug/` and a profdata file in `.build/x86_64-unknown-linux/debug/codecov/` on Linux which you are able to then pass along to `llvm-cov` to generate a report.

e.g.

```
$ llvm-cov report .build/x86_64-unknown-linux/debug/PredicatePackageTests.xctest -instr-profile=.build/x86_64-unknown-linux/debug/codecov/default.profdata -use-color
```

Which will generate a report like the following report:

[image: report]

See `llvm-cov report --help` for more information, it can even produce HTML reports.

Comment: I was looking for a solution to run on Travis CI, without XCode, and because of your post, I got to this one:

https://github.com/devmumbles/dev-mumbles/blob/master/.travis.yml

thanks! ^^

Comment: @HeitorSilva Are you sure the the json file can be processed by codecov.io? Either the link and mine shows "Coverage is either being processed, there has been no coverage report uploaded, or there was an error processing."

Comment: Also `swift test --show-codecov-path` return's the file of same json body with `llvm-cov export -format="text" ...`

Comment: hey @ERU!

I kinda abandoned this repo, so I'm not sure it works... probably not. Sorry.

Comment: Just one caveat with using `swift test`: it only works for Swift packages which don't rely on iOS-specific frameworks

Answer (score 5):

At the moment, I'm not aware of a tool that directly supports Linux. For what it's worth, we've still been happy with our code coverage solution that supports our web framework and HTTP server that runs on both Linux and macOS.

Our Swift Package Manager based project, [Kitura](https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Kitura), uses Travis CI for continuous integration. Each build will compile and run tests on *both* Linux and macOS. We also run a nightly build on Travis CI that generates coverage data, which is then uploaded to to codecov.io to generate reports like [this](https://codecov.io/gh/IBM-Swift/Kitura).

Under the covers, the build script runs `swift package generate-xcodeproj` and then `xcodebuild test` with code coverage enabled. Code coverage only runs on the macOS build environment, which contains `xcodebuild`. Since our Linux and macOS code paths are very similar, the coverage statistics are good enough for our purposes, and we are still running tests independently for each OS.

Comment: I was worried that would likely be the case. Will keep my eyes peeled for an answer. If anyone in the future comes across this and finds an alternative please add an answer.